# Merging csv files in directory based on Timestamps

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm currently learning Python for data manipulation. I've wrote a basic script to get two csv files and merge them based on Time Stamps and produce another csv file which is the result of those merged datasets.

However, I struggling to create a way to merge multiple csv files that are located in a directory based on TimeStamps. This is what I have currently:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

dataset1 = pd.read_csv('ds1.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=[0])
dataset2 = pd.read_csv('ds2.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=[0])

combinecsv = pd.merge(dataset1,dataset2, on='DateTime',how = 'outer')
combinecsv.to_csv(r"C:\Users\General\Documents\Data\combined.csv")

validcsv = pd.merge(dataset1,dataset2, on='DateTime',how = 'inner')
validcsv.to_csv(r"C:\Users\General\Documents\Data\valid.csv")
```

Any advice or directions on where to look at to be able to learn how to merge multiple (10+) csv files based on Time Stamps would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you struggling with a way to iterate over multiple files and are you looking to avoid repeating yourself in code going from two known to any number of unknown files? Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Sorry I explained it poorly, but basically if there was like 50 csv files, it'd be troublesome to go through and attempt to merge them all based on time stamps. Rather, a directory that contains all the CSV files is selected and for all the files there, it merges them based on the time stamps. This is just what I was thinking but there is probably more elegant and efficient ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list all the .csv files in a directory using pathlib's `Path.glob()`:

```
for csv in Path(r'C:\Temp').glob('*.csv'):
    # do something with csv
    pass
```

You can then add the contents and columns of each next .csv to the existing collection:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd


def add_dataset(old, new, **kwargs):
    if old is None:
        return new
    else:
        return pd.merge(old, new, **kwargs)


combined_csv = None
valid_csv = None

for csv in Path(r'C:\Temp').glob('*.csv'):
    dataset = pd.read_csv(csv, index_col=0, parse_dates=[0])
    combined_csv = add_dataset(combined_csv, dataset, on='DateTime', how='outer')
    valid_csv = add_dataset(valid_csv, dataset, on='DateTime', how='inner')

combined_csv.to_csv(r'C:\Temp\combined.csv')
valid_csv.to_csv(r'C:\Temp\valid.csv')
```

Note that running the script twice will include the outputs as inputs as well - writing them somewhere else may be advisable.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I hope the added fanciness of putting it in a function and passing the keyword arguments using `**kwargs` isn't confusing, I don't like repeating code. And you're welcome.

Comment: That part was new to me but it makes me go and read up on more content to actually understand what's going on. Ultimately makes it a good thing.

Comment: Hello again, sorry for coming back to this, I developed a GUI using Tkinter for a user to be able to easily select the path where the csv files are located and where they want the files to be outputted. However, when I try to run the script with a button I get an error saying: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_csv'`. Do you have any clue as to why this happens? Thanks!

Comment: A likely cause would be if there were no `*.csv` files in `C:\Temp`

Comment: My bad they were .xls. Thank you. Would you know by any chance why this error is now occurring: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'PY_VAR9\\combined.csv'`

Comment: This is likely not caused by the code as shown above - I expect you changed the next to last line and the path the script is trying to save `combined.csv` to does not exist (i.e. there is no folder 'PY_VAR9'), this is possibly due to your use of TkInter - please ask a fully qualified question elsewhere, since this is no longer really about this problem. Also, please pay close attention to what these error messages are telling you - I'm able to answer your questions with nothing but the error message and Google, which should be telling.